# angular js not storing records in value field

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-init="value = (total_rec - ans_rate)">
        <h4 ng-if="value<0">0</h4>
       <h4 ng-if="value>=0">{{total_rec - ans_rate}}</h4>
  </div>

I want to print 0 if result of total_rec - ans_rate comes 0 or less than 0, here total_rec & ans_rate is variables defined in angular file. please suggest me answers.
```

i want to implement this logic here 
ex.

```
var x= total_rec-ans_rate ;
    if (x <=0){
    print 0;
    }else{
    print x;
    }
```

but in this way :-

```
 <div ng-init="value = (total_rec - ans_rate)">
            <h4 ng-if="value<0">0</h4>
           <h4 ng-if="value>=0">{{total_rec - ans_rate}}</h4>
      </div>
```

please suggest me the proper way to do this.. Thanks..

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: Where are you init total_rec and ans_rate. share more code please

Comment: Works fine. see this: https://plnkr.co/edit/XhluiTNrTfZJdovopD7b?p=info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this make clear to you.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <div ng-init="value = cal_result()">
  <h4 ng-if="value < 0">0</h4>
  <h4 ng-if="value > 0">{{value}}</h4>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.total_rec =0;
      $scope.ans_rate = 3;
      $scope.cal_result = function () { 
        return $scope.total_rec - $scope.ans_rate;
      }
    });
    </script>
```